# "For" loop not processing all rows of data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a simple task sheet on Google Sheet that lets user enter notes. I have on the 4th column a Yes/No data validation for if the task is completed or not. I wrote code that will save the completed tasks to another sheet called "Back Log". Here's my code:

```
function Clear() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Main Note");
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Back Log");
  var u;
  var values = ss.getDataRange().getValues();
  var Rangecopy
  var rowNum2 = ss1.getLastRow();
  var rowNum3 = rowNum2 +1
  var Rangecopyto
  var colNum = 4;

  for (u=1;u<values.length +1;u++) {
    if (ss.getRange(u,colNum).getValue() =="Yes") {
      Rangecopy = ss.getRange(u,1,1,5)
      Rangecopyto = ss1.getRange(rowNum3,1,1,5);
      Rangecopy.copyTo(Rangecopyto);
      Rangecopy.clearContent();
      rowNum3 = rowNum3 +1;
    }
  }
}
```

The code does what I expect, except that it always leave the last entry untouched. Would appreciate any help on figuring out why.
I've added +1 to values.length which gives me the result I was looking for, but I think there may be a more proper way to do this.

Comment: I get a range invalid error when I change u in the for loop to 0. I also added a new line to declare value u first. I've edited the code to reflect on the changes.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the two dimensional array, and the row numbers in the spreadsheet are offset by one.  Row one in the spreadsheet, is index 0 in the array.  So, you must adjust for that.  You have a header row that you don't want to process, so you must start the count at 2.

```
var u=2;

for (u=2;u<values.length+1;u++) {
  if (ss.getRange(u,colNum).getValue() =="Yes") {
```

Comment: I change the code to above and now it removes the very first row, which contains the title of each column, but still leaves the last row untouched. Although it's probably not the ideal way, but I think I got it by adding +1 to values.length.

Comment: See updated answer.  Start `u` at 2 and add 1 to the length.